# Does cancelling a recurring payment profile from PayPal send an IPN (Instant Payment Notification)?

Tags: paypal

I'm having an issue where if I log in to Paypal and cancel a recurring payment profile, that sends an IPN (Instant Payment Notification) to my web server listener URL. At least, that's what I think is happening.

I configured my IPN listener code (C#) to take the Paypal response, extract certain data from it like the user's email address, their address, etc. I use their email address to create a new user in my aspnet_ membership tables. So, the idea is that the user makes a payment on my website via Paypal, and Paypal sends the response back to my website indicating success or failure (via the IPN). If success, then the code inserts a new user and provides the user with their credentials to log in. But, whenever I cancel a user's profile, it's at that point when another user (same user, and the user name is their email address) gets created in my database (the only place that does this is the IPN listener code).

**Does cancelling a recurring payment profile send another IPN to my server?**

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/q/2092358/1066234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PayPal sends an IPN when a recurring payment is cancelled. Also, they send an IPN:

- every year when the IPN renews,
- if the recurring payment is modified,
- if payment fails,
- or if the subscription expires.

This is documented on page 41 of the [IPN guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/ipnguide.pdf) (PDF file, July 10, 2012).

You will need to respond appropriately to the `txn_type` variable sent with the IPN to determine which action to take. It seems with your application, you will only want to create a new user if `txn_type = subscr_signup`.